# ionic server running in aws instance - how to access from windows PC browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, ionic-framework

I have installed Ionic in my AWS Linux instance. The 'ionic address' option gives 3 addresses - (1)Eth0(2)docker ip (3)localhost.

I have tried selecting each of these options and have tried connecting from my windows browser. But none of it works and ofcourse ping of all these IPs fail.

I have enabled the port 8100 in AWS instance and have tried connecting through the AWS public ip as well.

What am I doing wrongly - can someone pls help me here.

Comment: If you got solution, please post answer